# Big Commerce Variable for Shipping Method Chosen

Tags: bigcommerce

Anyone know what the variable is for specifying the shipping method chosen is in Big Commerce?  Trying to add the shipping method a customer chooses in the order confirmation email.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is not a variable that can be used in the confirmation email for the chosen shipping method, in my experience. The shipment email sends out the details based on what the user(Bigcommerce admin) has selected to ship the item out with, though.